# Get the value of a random parameter in pugixml

Tags: c++, pugixml

I have a question regarding the extraction of parameter values from an xml file using pugixml. I have an XML file with a hierarchical structure, and would like to retrieve the value associated with a specific parameter.

Part of the file looks like this:

```xml
<Path>
  <HardParameters>
   </HardParameters>
  <AdjustableParameters>
    <Parameter name="Path Bandwidth" units="rad/s">
      <symbol>wC</symbol>
      <description>Closed loop BW</description>
      <value>3.9</value>
      <reference>IEEE</reference>
     </Parameter>
     <Parameter name="Foo" units="">
      <symbol>zeta</symbol>
      <description>Foo ratio </description>
      <value>4.1</value>
      <reference>IEEE</reference>
     </Parameter>
  </AdjustableParameters>
</Path>
```

For instance, I would like to retrieve the value 4.1 of the Foo ratio.
I wonder if the function

```
xpath_variable* get( const char_t* name );
```

is the one I should use in this case? And how should it be used in such case? Just pass the name of the parameter as an argument?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use an XPath of `//Parameter[@name = 'Foo']/value/text()` to get the text of the `value` element inside a parameter with an attribute `name` with value `Foo`:

```
xml_node root
xpath_node value = root.select_node("//Parameter[@name = 'Foo']/value/text()");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just one more question, how can I extract the data as a double from 'value'? I saw an examlpe where the following happens:

double timeout = tool.attribute("Timeout").as_double();

I want to do a similar operation, but 'value' now does not have an attribute, right? Or is 4.1 regarded as an attribute?

Comment: I believe I found the answer:  
double paramValue = value.text().as_double();

is the way to go, I guess?

Comment: Your approach does not seem to work - I looks like value has to be of type xpath_node.